# How to return metric totals in GA4 using the PHP client library?

Tags: php, google-analytics-4, php-analytics-data

When using [php-data-analytics](https://github.com/googleapis/php-analytics-data), if I call `getTotals()` on the `runReport()` response, I get a "RepeatedField" object:

```
$params = [ 
    "property"      => "properties/{$property_id}",
    "dateRanges"    => [
        new DateRange([
            'start_date'    => '7daysAgo',
            'end_date'      => 'yesterday',
        ]),
        new DateRange([
            'start_date'    => '14daysAgo',
            'end_date'      => '8daysAgo',
        ])
    ],
    "dimensions"    => [
        new Dimension([ 'name' => 'nthDay' ])
    ],
    "metrics"       => [
        new Metric([ 'name' => 'activeUsers' ])
    ],
    "orderBys" => [
        new OrderBy([
            'desc'      => false,
            'dimension' => new OrderBy\DimensionOrderBy([
                "dimension_name"    => 'nthDay',
                "order_type"        => OrderBy\DimensionOrderBy\OrderType::NUMERIC
            ])
        ])
    ],
    "keepEmptyRows" => true
];

$report = $client->runReport($params);
$totals = $report->getTotals();
```

`$totals` is returned as the following object:

```
Google\Protobuf\Internal\RepeatedField Object
        (
            [container:Google\Protobuf\Internal\RepeatedField:private] => Array
                (
                )
        
            [type:Google\Protobuf\Internal\RepeatedField:private] => 11
            [klass:Google\Protobuf\Internal\RepeatedField:private] => Google\Analytics\Data\V1beta\Row
            [legacy_klass:Google\Protobuf\Internal\RepeatedField:private] => Google\Analytics\Data\V1beta\Row
        )
```

How do I use the GA4 PHP client library to return the totals for each of my metrics? According to [the official documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/rest/v1beta/RunReportResponse), this should return a Row object?

Comment: What is [`$property_id`](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/property-id)? `keepEmptyRows` may lead to `$totals`.

Comment: @MartinZeitler It's the ID of my GA4 property: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/rest/v1beta/properties/runReport#path-parameters

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [RepeatedField result](https://github.com/googleapis/php-analytics-data/blob/master/src/V1beta/RunReportResponse.php#L218) returned from calling `Google\Analytics\Data\V1beta\RunReportResponse::getTotals()` can [`be iterated`](https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/github.com/google/protobuf/+/HEAD/php/src/Google/Protobuf/Internal/RepeatedField.php#47).

> You must request a metric aggregation when you run the report to retrieve totals.

```php
use Google\Analytics\Data\V1beta\BetaAnalyticsDataClient;
use Google\Analytics\Data\V1beta\DateRange;
use Google\Analytics\Data\V1beta\Dimension;
use Google\Analytics\Data\V1beta\Metric;
use Google\Analytics\Data\V1beta\MetricAggregation;
use Google\Analytics\Data\V1beta\OrderBy;
use Google\Analytics\Data\V1beta\OrderBy\DimensionOrderBy;
use Google\Analytics\Data\V1beta\OrderBy\DimensionOrderBy\OrderType;

$property_id = '314116996';

$client = new BetaAnalyticsDataClient();

$params = [
    'property' => "properties/{$property_id}",
    'dateRanges' => [
        new DateRange([
            'start_date' => '7daysAgo',
            'end_date' => 'yesterday',
        ]),
        new DateRange([
            'start_date' => '14daysAgo',
            'end_date' => '8daysAgo',
        ]),
    ],
    'dimensions' => [
        new Dimension(['name' => 'nthDay']),
    ],
    'metrics' => [
        new Metric(['name' => 'activeUsers']),
    ],
    'orderBys' => [
        new OrderBy([
            'desc' => false,
            'dimension' => new DimensionOrderBy([
                'dimension_name' => 'nthDay',
                'order_type' => OrderType::NUMERIC,
            ]),
        ]),
    ],
    'keepEmptyRows' => true,
    'metricAggregations' => [
        MetricAggregation::TOTAL,
    ],
];

$response = $client->runReport($params);

$totals = $response->getTotals();

foreach ($totals as $row) {
    foreach ($row->getMetricValues() as $metricValue) {
        echo 'Metric Value: '.$metricValue->getValue().PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Comment: Running this doesn't print anything, but it also doesn't produce any errors. As a test, I tried `foreach($report->getTotals() as $row) print 'test'.PHP_EOL;` and nothing was printed.

Comment: Can you share if you're requesting metrics in parameters passed in `client->runReport` array and if you have data within the requested `dateRange` for the GA property?

Comment: Yes, I'm requesting metrics and can confirm it's returning data by looping through the Row objects reutnred by `$report->getRows()`. I've updated my question to include the parameters I'm passing to `runReport()`. I'm confused as to how I can call `foreach` on `$report->getTotals()`, yet print nothing from within that loop - not even a simple string - and also not generate an error.

Comment: @HWD You must request metrics aggregation to retrieve totals in the run report response.

Comment: Do you know why the aggregate total for activeUsers is less than the sum total returned for the date range? For example, the dateRange shows 16 activeUsers, but the aggregate returns 5.

Comment: You could print the dimension values returned in the Repeated Field result to have an idea of the dimensions that the aggregate is for.

Answer (score -1):

There's a [GA4 Dimensions & Metrics Explorer](https://ga-dev-tools.web.app/ga4/dimensions-metrics-explorer/), which can be used to build requests.
When having a request which yields results, it's not so difficult to port it to PHP then.
Dimension name `nthDay` may actually be `ga:nthDay` (at least for UA).